# Error while running the code to show the mesh using facemesh from tensorflow.js

Tags: html, tensorflow.js

I am getting this error while running the code which uses facemesh model of tensorflow-models. I have already included the scripts

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-core"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/facemesh"></script>
```

However it is not able to display the mesh and I am getting warnings:

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tf-core.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tf-converter.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

I tried to find the alternative sources. However no luck yet. If someone has resolved this issue, please let me know. It would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you did get that script tag, but the official cdn for tensorflowjs is:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```

Source:
https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/setup

Comment: The scripts include the pre-requisites of facemesh as described here https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/facemesh. I included above script. I got error. Uncaught (in promise) Error: Tensorflow Op is not supported: _FusedConv2D
    at t.mapNode (operation_mapper.ts:125)
    at operation_mapper.ts:86
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at t.transformGraph (operation_mapper.ts:85)
    at t.<anonymous> (graph_model.ts:125)
    at callbacks.ts:17
    at Object.next (callbacks.ts:17)
    at a (callbacks.ts:17)